# Mirror API and Navigation

Tags: google-mirror-api

I want to create a Menuitem, which in turn could open a navigation map or something that can be used for navigation. Does Google Glass Mirror API support this?

If yes, what is the correct way to do it?

From what I can see in the docs, it can only create map. But doesnt say anything about triggering the navigation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to insert a timeline item that has two pieces of information that aren't normally included:

1. You will need to create a MenuItem with an action of "NAVIGATE"
2. Your TimelineItem needs to have a location set (which is where it will navigate to)

See https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert for more about creating the TimelineItem and https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/locations more more about the location object. But if you were inserting a card to let people navigate to Google HQ, the JSON representation might be something like this:

```
{
  "text": "Go to Google HQ",
  "location": {
    "latitude": 37.422,
    "longitude": -122.084058,
    "displayName": "Googleplex",
    "address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043"
  },
  "menuItems": [
    "action": "NAVIGATE"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If the answer meets your needs, you should accept it as an answer. Glad it helped you out!

Comment: My bad, this is my first time posting on stack overflow.

Comment: Not a problem, just helping you understand how things work. Welcime to so!